# Is there anything like inner join in Elasticsearch

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, elasticsearch, inner-join

I am using inner join in my MySql table in order to join a FK into another table so that I can print out "state names" together with the result.

And now after switching to ES I have hit my first problem. Does ES have any function like mysql's **inner join**?

I have looked into nested objects. Is this anything that I assign to the query or do I apply these settings when I am mapping?

What I want to do is to insert another index in ES. That index holds id_state and stateNames.

So when I do a search query I want to make a join between stateID and id_state so that I can print out the stateNames from the second index together with the search result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer: No. Elasticsearch is a NoSQL, document DB & full text search engine. Not a relational DB.

A more detailed explanation of the differences here:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relations.html

You *might* be able to make something work for your "State" and "StateID" example using Parent/Child relationships - more here, as I don't have enough information about your use case.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child.html

Good luck!